# Successfully installed Ubuntu Asus laptop. After booting Windows system won't Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 18 LTS on my Asus laptop model X441B. The next day I booted to Windows 10. Now I can't boot to Ubuntu. When I enter the BIOS Ubuntu is there, first in the boot order, but when I select it, it just boots to Windows. Then when I shut down, Windows said it was repairing the disc. So I booted into Ubuntu using my USB stick, in try Ubuntu mode. When I chose the install option, it detected the old installation and didn't do anything. 
Now when I chose Ubuntu in theBIOS it asks me to set the time and doesn't boot. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) Secure Boot disabled in BIOS? 2) Fast Start used in Windows? 3) Was RSTe, RAID, or ACPI drive mode set in BIOS? 4) Was Windows completely shut down before you installed Ubuntu, or was it set for Hibernation or Fast Sleep? 5) Did you install Desktop 19.04.3 or Server 18.04.3, or some other release number? 6) Was the ISO used to make a LiveUSB checked for download errors by tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Please respond to items 1-4 by clicking edit and add answers to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

My hint is:

1) Disable fast startup on windows

2) If it still doesnt work, boot in your live usb on try ubuntu, install boot-repair and launch it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```